# Some codes JavaScript do not work from calling AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cordova

I am working on the application of phones on the platform cordova, I am calling some data from the database via AJAX The problem is that this file holds some JavaScript code it works once and again does not work.
As the information in the browser works perfectly but when you convert it to an application and install it on the phone it is once working and once these codes do not work.

I tried to change the results for example :
`1`

```
success : function(reponse){
document.getElementById("myincomeID").innerHTML = reponse;
}
```

to

```
success : function(reponse){
$('#myincomeID').html(reponse);
}
```

`2`
or change in code ajax file :

```
var el = document.getElementById('checkboxElem<?=$uidimg?>');
el.addEventListener('long-press', function(e) {

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxmsgcss');
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].style.display ="block";
}
var elements2 = document.querySelectorAll('.cardstylecssmsg');
for(var i=0; i<elements2.length; i++){
    elements2[i].style.width ="85%";
}
    localStorage.setItem("display",'OK');
    document.getElementById("logoodID").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("logoodID2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("logoodID3").style.display = "block";

});
```

to with `$('document').ready(function(){ //code });`mean :

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var el = document.getElementById('checkboxElem<?=$uidimg?>');
el.addEventListener('long-press', function(e) {

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxmsgcss');
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].style.display ="block";
}
var elements2 = document.querySelectorAll('.cardstylecssmsg');
for(var i=0; i<elements2.length; i++){
    elements2[i].style.width ="85%";
}
    localStorage.setItem("display",'OK');
    document.getElementById("logoodID").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("logoodID2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("logoodID3").style.display = "block";

});
});
```

But it did not solve the problem

Comment: Code wrapped in document.ready will only execute when the web page finishes loading for the first time, not after an ajax call.  It seems hacky to load javascript with ajax instead of just a script tag.

Comment: @James - yes in `document.ready`  but is not problem if working, this is fin .the problem sometimes is never works after ajax call or after page finishes loading.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who has the same problem
I will put here the solution I have done for this problem :

As mentioned above, the application did not occupy certain tasks when browsing and passing from page to page.
The shaper is in my application I put the file that includes the function :

```
var el = document.getElementById('checkboxElem<?=$uidimg?>');
el.addEventListener('long-press', function(e) { //function});
```

I mean here : `long-press` = `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>`

The file `myscript.js` that contains the function is placed in the same file as the AJAX of course
**But I did not call the file in the rest of the pages**
When I browse the rest of the pages and then return to the same page does not work code .Until **I called the same file in the rest of the pages** = `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>`